# Запуск firefox из crontab

Tags: cron

Как запустить firefox из crontab на ubuntu? Пробовал пару вариантов, не работает.

Comment: Неужели никто не может помочь?

Comment: Если вы разобрались, то напишите ответ

Answer (score 0):

Сделал описание в теле скрипта здесь:

- https://github.com/KeyJoo/desertos/blob/master/devops/firefox-cron.sh
  Если буду вопросы, спрашивай.
- А так я сам долго не мог понять, почему не могу добавить в `crontab` скрипт. Вот в гисте опсал по шагам: https://gist.github.com/KeyJoo/b018812b85eefae6ee2be27a574787be
- Если в системе не установлен `postfix`, как это было у меня, то вопрос быстрее решится.

Ещё мне помог короткий мануал https://awc.com.my/uploadnew/5ffbd639c5e6eccea359cb1453a02bed_Setting%20Up%20Cron%20Job%20Using%20crontab.pdf
точнее все чтения в совокупности. + `man crontab` + пару ссылок на книжки.