# Зaпуск браузера из cron на ubuntu 14

Tags: firefox, cron

Здравствуйте! Как запустить браузер firefox из cron в ubuntu14? Делаю так:
В планировщике в ISP5:

```
/bin/bash /start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Содержимое start.sh:

```
#/bin/bash
xhost +local:root 
export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/bin/firefox "http://site.ru/test.php"
```

Запускаю из ISP и пишет:

```
root# /bin/bash /start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Но ничего не происходит. Как всё-таки наконец-то запустить firefox и ссылку в нём?
`echo $DISPLAY` в терминале показывает `:1.0`, но `export DISPLAY=:1.0` я так же пробовал и результата нету так же.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запуск firefox из crontab](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/799266/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-firefox-%d0%b8%d0%b7-crontab)

Comment: А толку? Ответа что там, что здесь нет.

Comment: Изобрёл свой костыль и всё работает отлично.

Comment: Дополните вопрос вашим решением.  Что происходит при запуске скрипта в терминале?